# Connection between HTML table and MySql database troubleshooting

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't find the misstake in the following code.
I have a html Table with the fixed values item und price and calculated value total and the input value quantity

the calculation.js works fine as well as the connection to the database.
it just cant find the array keys and tells me this if i click the button

```
Warning: Undefined array key "username" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kulinarik\order_save.php on line 7
Warning: Undefined array key "item" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kulinarik\order_save.php on line 8
Warning: Undefined array key "quantity" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kulinarik\order_save.php on line 9
```

this is the code

**html**

```
                  <form method="POST" action="order_save.php">  
                <table class="u-table-entity" src="jquery.js">

                  <script scr="calculation.js"></script>
                  
                  <colgroup>
                    <col width="20%">
                    <col width="2.1%">
                    <col width="22%">
                    <col width="21.7%">
                    <col width="34.2%">
                  </colgroup>
                  <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                    <tr style="height: 55px;">
                      <b>
                      <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                      </th>
                      <th class="u-table-cell"></th>
                      <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></th>
                      <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></th>
                      <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></th>
                      </b>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 55px;">
                      <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <input type="text" class="item" value="Kornspitz" name="item" placeholder="Kornspitz" readonly />
                      </td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <input type="text" class="price" value="1.39" name="price" readonly/>
                      </td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell">
                        <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity"/> 
                      </td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell">
                        <input type="text" class="total" name="total" readonly/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="height: 55px;">
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-19"> Gesamtpreis:</td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 56px;">
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-24">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="u-active-none u-border-none u-btn u-button-link u-button-style u-hover-none u-none u-text-custom-color-1 u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-btn-1" href="https://nicepage.com">AGB</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-25">
                        <a class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-1 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-btn-2" type="submit" href="order_save.php">BESTELLUNG</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </form>
```

**php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
    <?php
    $con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'orders');
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    ?>
```

the username i want to add is from the session_login
maybe there is a way to add this too ?
it is created with this code

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<?php
    $ldap_dn = "uid=".$_POST["username"].",dc=example,dc=com";
    $ldap_password = $_POST["password"];
    $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap.forumsys.com");
    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
        {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];
        header("Location: Startseite.php");
        }
    else
        {
        echo "Invalid Credential";
        }
?>
```

I would really appreciate your help
thanks

Comment: If you have a `<form>` you have to have some form items, such as `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc. The HTML table itself is just displaying values on the screen, it's not form elements that will be posted back to the server on a submission. [Read a turorial such as this one](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/07/creating-simple-form-using-php-and-mysql) to also be aware of XSS, SQL injections, etc. There are several steps to get all that working.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];` makes no sense because there's no `username` field in your form. If you want to get the username _from_ the session, then assign the session value to a variable, not the other way round! e.g.  this probably makes more sense: `$username = $_SESSION["username"];`

Comment: Anyway `<a class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-1 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-btn-2" type="submit" href="order_save.php">BESTELLUNG</a>` makes no sense. 1) a href link can only submit a GET, not a POST. 2) It's submitting it to a different location than the "action" of the form, so the code is inconsistent and unclear about what should happen, 3) `type="submit"` isn't a recognised attribute for an `<a` and won't do anything. It only works on buttons/inputs. You need to use a button to submit your form. Please - study tutorials / documentation / examples more carefully!

Comment: @ Patrick Janser
There are Input fields in the table?

@ADyson
I understand the confusion
I edited the code and enterd the whole script

Thanks for your comments

Comment: You'd still need to write `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` in the first script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you should use the proper button for submitting the form, not a link. The link button is only redirecting you to the PHP page, while the form was not been submitted.

Your form should look like this:

```
              <form method="POST" action="order_save.php">  
            <table class="u-table-entity" src="jquery.js">

              <script scr="calculation.js"></script>
              
              <colgroup>
                <col width="20%">
                <col width="2.1%">
                <col width="22%">
                <col width="21.7%">
                <col width="34.2%">
              </colgroup>
              <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                <tr style="height: 55px;">
                  <b>
                  <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="u-table-cell"></th>
                  <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></th>
                  <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></th>
                  <th class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></th>
                  </b>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 55px;">
                  <td class="u-table-cell">
                      <input type="text" class="item" value="Kornspitz" name="item" placeholder="Kornspitz" readonly />
                  </td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell">
                      <input type="text" class="price" value="1.39" name="price" readonly/>
                  </td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell">
                    <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity"/> 
                  </td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell">
                    <input type="text" class="total" name="total" readonly/>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 55px;">
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-19"> Gesamtpreis:</td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 56px;">
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-24">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="u-active-none u-border-none u-btn u-button-link u-button-style u-hover-none u-none u-text-custom-color-1 u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-btn-1" href="https://nicepage.com">AGB</a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-25">
                    <button class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-1 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-btn-2" type="submit" value="BEST SELLING"></button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
```

Moreover, assign a value to $username.
This will not work

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"]

There is no input field in your form where a username is present. Fix that and that may get your program running

Comment: You've spotted the problem with the link, but 1) your replacement button will have no text in it, and 2) you haven't solved the problem with the username (see one of my comments above for a suggestion)

Comment: Thanks for your comment
I just added the Text between <button>text</button>

Comment: It is still proper. I feel you should use value="text" instead for the button text

Comment: there is a session from where de 'username' comes
This is from the login